# Use Adwords API (MccApp) in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-ads-api

I have a custom API written in GAS (Google Apps Script) and would like to utilize the Adwords API from within it.

Sometimes used along with the MccApp, the service is readily available from within Adwords Scripts itself (My Client Center > Scripts).

For Example:

```
            function account(client) {
              var result = {
                  'id': null,
                  'campaigns': {}
              }
              result.id = client.getCustomerId()
              var currentAct = AdWordsApp.currentAccount()
              MccApp.select(client)
              var campaignIterator = AdWordsApp.campaigns().get()
              while (campaignIterator.hasNext()) {
                  var campaign = campaignIterator.next()
                  result.campaigns[campaign.getName()] = campaign.getId()
              }
              MccApp.select(currentAct)
              return result
            }
```

However, this API is not readily available inside a Google Apps Script. I have tried enabling it under "Resources > Advanced Google Services" and also under the developer console, but the UI offers no option that I can see.

QUESTION: Is it possible to enable use of the AdwordsApp and MccApp inside a Google Apps script so that the above code snippet would work in GAS?

If not, I understand already there are two workarounds:

1. Just use Adwords Script
2. Communicate with the API from GAS as though it were an external service (i.e... using SOAP, REST, etc...)

Comment: So, you already know about `UrlFetchApp.fetchApp(the url)` ?  [Google Documentation - UrlFetchApp Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

Comment: Yes, but I am hoping there is a way to use the Adwords API in GAS in the same way that it is used in an Adwords Script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much research, there really is no way to add the MccApp and AdwordsApp services for use in a Google Apps script. The nearest solution is to communicate with the API as though it were external or just use an Adwords Script.

Comment: Did you checkeout https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external ?

Comment: This is an old thread, so things might have changed since I last asked this question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be able to get to the **AdWord API** through the **Management API**:

See the **Conceptual Overview** section:

> AdWords Links can be constructed at the Web Property level.

[Google Developer Guide - What Is The Management API - Overview](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/)

and you can get to the Management API with the Google Analytics API.

Quote:

> The Analytics service allows you to use the Google Analytics
>   Management API and Reporting APIs in Apps Script

[Google Documentation - Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/analytics)

So, you need to use the **RESOURCES** menu, Choose, **ADVANCED GOOGLE SERVICES**, and then turn the **Google Analytics API** on.

With the **Google Analytics API**, you can access the **Management API**.

Comment: Damn... I thought that might have been the answer, but there are no Adwords links there.